# My Control Panel and online IP addess tools report different results for my IP address

Tags: windows, attacks, ip

Control Panel says it's 192.168.1.1; Google, whatismyipaddress.com etc. says it's 75.92.141.32

When I put the IP address reported online in my address bar I get a Nokia login page, but my ISP is Clear. I think someone may be trying to hack my computer or something.

Comment: This is not a security issue - so is off topic here. Understanding IP addresses is basic networking knowledge.

Answer (score 5):

The first IP address `192.168.1.1` is a local (private) IP address for your computer on your local network.  IP addresses that start with `192.168.x.x`, `172.16.x.x - 172.31.x.x`, and `10.x.x.x` are private addresses to be used for [private networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network).  This is so large private networks (that aren't hosting services to be accessed by the outside world directly) do not need to be assigned unique IP addresses (as there are only about 4 billion IPv4 addresses).  It would be problematic if two machines doing different functions were assigned the same IP address on the actual internet, but its no problem if you and I both have devices on our local home networks with the address of `192.168.1.1`.

The other IP address (starting with `75.92.x.x`) is your real IP for the router you are connecting through that was assigned to you by your ISP.  Your home router performs [Network Address Translation (NAT)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAT) to route packets going to from your computer with a local address to the internet.

For example, let's say you request to see a website at `1.2.3.4` on port 80.  Your computer makes that request from a randomly assigned port that it is not using (say 34567) from `192.168.1.1`.  Your computer knows to send network requests to your home's router (there's probably an entry in the routing table saying forward everything that's not 127.0.0.1 to the local router).  The router sees the destination isn't on the home network, so changes the source IP address of the request in the IP layer to its own assigned IP address before forwarding the packet out on the actual internet (NAT may also change the source port, but for this example I'll assume it doesn't).   Then when the response comes back from `1.2.3.4` port 80 to the router to your router's IP address (at the port 34567), your router changes the destination of the IP packet to 192.168.1.1 port 34567 (as your router remembered 192.168.1.1 made the request) and continues to route it to your device on the local network.  So to the outside world you are the address that doesn't start with `192.168.1.1`, but on your local network you are `192.168.1.1`.

Also, the addresses `192.168.1.1`/`192.168.0.1` by convention tend to be the address of your actual router in home network scenarios.  Typically, the IP address assigned to each computer on your local network is something like `192.168.1.101`.